# Placing 1 in n x n board of zeroes, such that all rows and all columns have same parity

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

I am working on the following task:

> Given a  x  board, and  buttons on it, press at least one button in such a way that the count of the pressed buttons in each row and column is of the same parity.
>
> #### Input
>
> , 
> <sub>1</sub>, <sub>1</sub>
> <sub>2</sub>, <sub>2</sub>
> ...
> ,
>
> Where  is the length of the side of the square board,  is the number of buttons on the board, and ,  are the coordinates of the <sup>th</sup> button.
>
> #### Output
>
> If there is no solution, output "NO".
>
> Otherwise, output "YES", followed by the indexes of the pressed buttons.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>
> - ≤ <sup>2</sup>, and  ≤ 2⋅10<sup>5</sup>

### My solution attempts:

We can imagine the input as a x matrix of all zeros. Some matrix cells have the possibility to be set to 1 (these are the "buttons"). We must set at least one cell to 1. We could set more to 1, but only cells that have this capability ("buttons"). If we can find a way to give each column and each row a sum that are all either even or all odd, we have a solution.

I discovered that in the case where the sum of the buttons in each row and column is even and such an answer exists, then the vertices (buttons) form a kind of cycle by merging with another vertex in the same row or column. But such information doesn't really give me anything; the computational complexity will still be high.

### Example:

Here, a 'B' is a button and a '-' is a cell with no button. The only solution for this example is to press all buttons, leaving all rows and columns with a parity of 1.

```
BBB-
---B
---B
---B
```

How can we solve this efficiently?

Comment: Initially, each field has a value of 0(there are buttons on some fields). If we run a button, then in the field where there is a button there will be a value of 1. The task is to make the sum in each row and column the same parity.

Comment: Formally if we have n rows: r1, r2...rn
And n columns:
c1, c2.... cn.
Then we want each of r1, r2...rn, c1, c2...cn to have the same remainder from dividing by 2.
We need to run at least one button

Comment: In the case where the sum of the buttons in each row and column is even, then pressing all the buttons will leave every row and column with even parity.

Comment: You can find a cycle in a graph using any graph traversal algorithm like DFS or BFS.

Comment: For each parity, you can default and eliminate from your graph all buttons whose row sum or col sum equals one.

Comment: @phatfingers Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: It's just an optimization.  Count the buttons for every row and column.  For every button participating in a count of 1, there is only one possible value for that button.  Each must match your parity value, so you can reduce the size of your graph.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I suggest a process similar to [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) mod 2.  This can take up to O(nm) time:

- Make an array `R` of size 2n.  Indexes 0 to n-1 will correspond to rows, while indexes n to 2n-1 will correspond to columns.
- Iterate through the buttons converting `(x,y)` to a tuple of indexes `(i,j)` in `R`, with `i < j`:  `(x,y) => (y, x+n)`
- Each tuple is a candidate *representative* for its smallest index.  If `R[i]` is empty, then set `R[i] = (i,j)`, and proceed to the next tuple.
- Otherwise, let `(i, j2) = R[i]` make a new tuple containing `j` and `j2` with the smallest index first.  If `j!=j2`, then this is a new candidate representative for the new smallest index.  Otherwise, return YES, because you've found an even-parity solution to the problem.

Note that each candidate representative tuple represents the effect of toggling some *set* of buttons, and when we combine two tuples, we combine those sets.

If you've processed all the buttons and haven't returned YES, then there is no even parity solution, and all the buttons are linearly independent.

To see if there's an odd parity solution, iterate through `R[0]` to `R[2n-1]`, selecting each representative for a row or column that has the wrong parity, and flip the rows and/or columns corresponding to its two indexes.  If you find a row/column with even parity and no representative, then return NO, because there's no solution. If you make it to the end, then you've set all rows/columns to odd parity and the answer is YES.

The implementation is simpler than the explanation:

```python
def sameParity(n, buttons):

    reps=[0]*(2*n)
    for (x,y) in buttons:
        i = y
        j = x+n
        while reps[i] > 0:
            j2 = reps[i]
            if j2 == j:
                # Even parity solution
                return True
            i = min(j,j2)
            j = j + j2 - i # the other one
        reps[i] = j

    # no even parity solution. try odd
    parities = [False]*(2*n)
    for i in range(2*n):
        if not parities[i]:
            if reps[i] < 1:
                return False
            parities[i] = True
            parities[reps[i]] = not parities[reps[i]]
    return True 

N = 3
buttons = [(2,1),(1,2),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
print(sameParity(N, buttons))
```

Comment: You aren't saying the answer is no otherwise, right?

Comment: I was, but I was assuming even parity.  I switched to a different algorithm that works for both.

Comment: not working for:
6 11
1 6
6 1
2 2
3 6
3 5
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 1
4 5
5 5
We can press: (1, 6), (6, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5)

Comment: It works, but I started counting rows and columns at 0, not 1, so the numbers should go from 0-5.